# How to know when UIView becomes completely hidden?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiresponder

I am **switching between two views by toggling hidden** attributes. How would I know when one view gets hidden and/or visible?

Tried setting break points into viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear, becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder. Nothing. None of those are called, when I set hidden = YES/NO.

```
if (self.aController)
    self.aController.view.hidden = YES;
if (self.bController)
    self.bController.view.hidden = NO;
[self.bController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

I call viewWillAppear by myself, since that view is... subview of subview of view under UITabBarItem. Apple docs told that the setup is unnatural and **some automatic notifications have to be done manually**. Is this the same problem with not getting becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder which are supposed to be related to hidden status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess Apple docs were right - or at least offered **one way to solve the problem**. Since I don't get automatic notifications in subViews, but I do get them in mainView, I just "forward" the notifications by myself:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// called at tab switch
if (self.aController)
    [self.aController viewWillAppear:YES];
if (self.bController)
    [self.bController viewWillAppear:YES];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

// called at tab switch
if (self.aController)
    [self.aController viewWillDisappear:YES];
if (self.bController)
    [self.bController viewWillDisappear:YES];
}
```

Not sure, if this is the "right" way, but it works. Next problem, please!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use [Key-Value Observation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/index.html) to observe the `hidden` property of either views. When the change is triggered, you'll get a message about the change.

Comment: Just to update: good idea, but I couldn't use it because switching from one tab to another doesn't change hidden property. I could change it myself, but calling viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear was easier choice. Thanx anyway, have to recall Key-Value Observation!